# Why am I getting a new session when using async actions and RedirectToAction in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, async-await

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application that is exhibiting session management problems.

I'm using the Session to track the logged in user. I have a custom action filter that checks a user is logged in and, if not, redirects to the log in page.

This *generally* works fine. However, I have a problem where a new session is getting created during a certain request. The session ID is the same, but the Session.IsNewSession property shows it's a new session - and the session contents have gone.

The action where is happens is an async action (using the async/await features in .NET 4.5). I *don't* manipulate the session in the thread that is invoked with the await keyword. When the await operation completes, I then do a RedirectToAction to display the results of the operation.

When I check the session, just before executing the action I've redirected it to - it has the custom access attribute on it - that's when I find a new session has been created (so the authentication fails and I'm return to the login page).

I use RedirectToAction at numerous points in the application, so that can't be the issue (or at least the *only* issue). Could the problem be something to do with the async/await call - even though I don't use or need the session within the code that is invoked by the await?

Is returning the ASP.NET thread to the pool and getting it back invalidating the session? If so, what's the solution? Can I save and restore the session across the await? Or will I have to implement some custom logic that records that the user was logged in in my database, for example?

Comment: async in the server-side code? this is bad situation.

Comment: `async` shouldn't cause session problems. Are you using `ConfigureAwait(false)` at all? And can you post a minimal repro?

Comment: Check http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: @GrantThomas asynchronous HTTP handlers are supported since ASP.NET 1.0 and asynchronous page tasks for pages since ASP.NET 2.0. With the introduction of **async**/**await** ASP.NET benefited from it in HTTP handlers, web form pages and MVC controllers. And since the request handling thread pool is a scarse resource, it can be a very good idea.

Comment: @PauloMorgado: I believe it was .NET 1.1, actually. Either way, asynchronous code on the server side is certainly not new! :)

Comment: [IHttpAsyncHandler Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.aspx) Supported in: 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0

One could say it's native to the platform. :)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the problem was being caused by a Win32 DLL I'm using that was "touching" (i.e. changing the timestamp on) a config file. This was causing the web app to be reloaded at that point - thus invalidating the session.

Answer (score -1):

I got this behavior when the green arrow at the top of Visual Studio Professional 2017 was set to "IIS Express". When I changed it to "IIS Express (Google Chrome)" my session variables quit disappearing every time I called RedirectToAction. I read in one of the posts that it could be related to the browser cookies.